# git lfs pull restores deleted files

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have tracked some files in a Git repository with LFS and everything is in a clean state. When I delete an LFS-tracked file and then call `git lfs pull`, as my CI build script needs to do, the deleted file is immediately restored. Doing this before a commit would effectively prevent deleting LFS-tracked files.

How can I tell git-lfs to only pull those files that are actually referenced in the current working directory? If a pointer file is not there, that certainly has a reason.

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579211/how-to-delete-a-file-tracked-by-git-lfs-and-release-the-storage-quota

Answer (score 1):

It's not surprising this happens. `git lfs pull` **explicitly** requests that the state from the remote is merged into your current state – and hence, files that exist on the remote will be restored.

So, simply don't `pull` before you `commit`. That's the way git is supposed to work. Nothing broken here but your usage.

Comment: I'm using a build&commit script that checks the build before committing. That workflow uses the same build script as the CI server. I'd really like to keep it that way...

Comment: yeah well, but you can't pull before you commit. That simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why do the pointer files even exist if lfs-pull can download the files anyway? Is it supposed to have any meaning if those pointer files exist or not?