# Delete large file from git/lfs folder

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I recently pushed a ~130 Mb file to my Github repo using LFS. I then realized this was a bad idea and removed it.

The problem is that it is still there tacking up space in my history and my quota:

[image]

According to the answers given here [How to delete a file tracked by git-lfs and release the storage quota?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579211/how-to-delete-a-file-tracked-by-git-lfs-and-release-the-storage-quota) and [Github's own docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-git-large-file-storage#git-lfs-objects-in-your-repository) the only solution to remove this file is to **delete and recreate the repo**. This is of course *insane*.

So my question: can I simply remove the large file stored inside the `/.git/lfs` folder? The full path looks like this:

```
/path_to_my_repo/.git/lfs/objects/f4/f0/f4f05bce7c2660dcb85c4eaf709bc2d161eb758b3ccd54ffa474f49f0e4bd684
```

Will this destroy my repo or is it safe?

Comment: This will still not delete it on the server, only on your local machine.

Comment: If github does not allow you to list and manipulate individual files in the LFS storage, like some others hosters at least has done before, then you're stuck with what their official docs say.